# Jquery Selector to get value of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts

I want to take values of multiple textarea and display them as tool tip of a highcharts graph.I used input and eq selector to get values of multiple text areas but the values are not getting returned as tooltip..

HTML code..

```
<div id="dialog" title="Input Data">
<form id="pForm" >
 <!--name: <input type="text" name="name" width='50' height='100' maxlength="10" placeholder="Fill in your data" /><br><br>-->

<label for="txt1">Data 1:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt1"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 1"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt2">Data 2:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt2"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 2"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt3">Data 3:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <textarea id="txt3"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 3"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt4">Data 4:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt4"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 4"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt5">Data 5:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt5"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 5"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt6">Data 6:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt6"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 6"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt7">Data 7:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt7"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 7"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt8">Data 8:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt8"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 8"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt9">Data 9:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt9"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 9"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt10">Data 10:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt10"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 10"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt11">Data 11:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt11"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 11"></textarea><br><br>

<label for="txt12">Data 12:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="txt12"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2" maxlength="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="Data 12"></textarea><br><br>


&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="getdata()" />
<input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="getPdata( this.value )" />
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript code..

```
             tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {

            var serieI = this.series.index;
                        var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
                        var index1= dataValues2.indexOf(this.y);
            debugger;
            var comment = "";
            if (serieI == 0) {
                comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();

            } else {

                comment = $("input:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();

            }
            return 'The value for, <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>' + comment;

                          //return '<b>'+ myText[this.point.x] +'</b>';

                    /*var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
                    var comment=$("input:eq("+(index)+")").val()
                    return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
                    '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b> -->'+comment;*/
            }
        }
```

I cannot understand the error..the fiddle is also here http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/8/ In this fiddle text-boxes have been used whereas i want to use text areas..

Please Help..

Comment: Is the fiddle working for you with textboxes?

Comment: yes...but when i try using the code for text areas then it doesn't work..you can see the link to verify..

Comment: Have you tried `$("textarea:eq(" + (index) + ")")` ?

Comment: It works fine for me.... http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/11/

Comment: Will this work if I display the text areas inside a Jquery ui custom dialog to take input from user and then display tooltip??

Answer (score 3):

Check sample on fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/10/

Use textarea for selector instead of input as below

```
if (serieI == 0) {
      comment = $("textarea:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
} else {
      //comment = "second serie matched!";
      comment = $("textarea:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I display the text areas inside a Jquery ui custom dialog to take input from user and then display tooltip??

Comment: @Lucy: Yes it will work, but need to use proper selectors for custom dialog box and textarea inside it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `input` to `:input`:

```
comment = $(":input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
comment = $(":input:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/12/)

Comment: @Archer `:input` can select all form elements, i hope you know it.

Comment: Will this work if I display the text areas inside a Jquery ui custom dialog to take input from user and then display tooltip??